# Chrome extension hint.js & ngHintModules

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Our angular app sometime does not load on chrome canary (Version 41.0.2237.0 canary (64-bit)) saying

> Failed to instantiate module ngHintModules due to: RangeError: Maximum
>   call stack size exceeded

But it loads fine in firefox, chrome (Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)), safari.

Probably not sure whether there is something to do with angular or not.

Full error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngHintModules due to:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at module.exports (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2333:21)
    at module.exports (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2384:5)
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2387:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at module.exports (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2385:21)
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2387:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at module.exports (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2385:21)
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2387:7
```

NB: The Error I am showing here is from

> Version 41.0.2237.0 canary (64-bit)

Comment: They must have just pushed an update out to the chrome store because I'm getting it now too.

Comment: Yeah, this bug was introduced earlier today by the new 0.5.0 version of Chrome AngularJS Batarang extension. Disable it for now until https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/157 is fixed.

Comment: I was working late on a project last night, changed a lot of code, got up today and it was not working. After 30 minutes of scratching my head, a quick google brought me here. This issue was affecting me too.

Comment: Just happened to me with 0.7.4

Answer (score 47):

I also had this problem which was resolved by disabling Batarang.

Comment: Although this solutions works, you can find a temporary workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27404493/464257).

Comment: Whilst useful, this answer should point to ppoliani's answer, which is both correct and shows you how to fix it by making your code more DRY.

Answer (score 28):

This issue is opened on the Batarang Github here: https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/156

You can load the prior version of Batarang from this zip file: https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/archive/v0.4.3.zip

1. Open More Tools->Extensions in Chrome
2. Locate AngularJS Batarang and click on the trash can to remove the extension
3. Download the [.zip](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/archive/v0.4.3.zip)
4. Extract the file
5. Open More Tools->Extensions in Chrome
6. Check Developer Mode at the top
7. Click 'Load unpacked extension'
8. Select the directory where you extracted the zip
9. If you get an error about the manifest file, then you probably selected one directory level too high. Make sure that you select the bottom level angularjs-batarang-0.4.3 directory
10. Load up an AngularJS page and use Batarang again with Inspector just like before

This will restore the previous version which while having issues does have some mostly working features like Performance profiling, scope inspector, options, and a help tab which are gone from the latest version. The 0.7.1 version fixes the major breakage of apps, but it only provides the scope tree (no inspector) and the new angular-hint functionality.

Comment: Note: you might also need to enable, then disable Batarang in the console's AngularJS tab in order to reactivate access to "$scope" in the console.

Comment: I had to disable the newer version as well after applying the above steps. I had 2 Batarang's going.

Comment: Thanks, just added a step to disable the extension first before installing the unpacked 0.4.3 version. Brian has pushed out a 0.7.1 version to the Chrome store that has some fixes. I'm not sure that it is stable yet though.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to disable Angular batarang; just do the following:

1. Open the developer tools and navigate to the hint.js file (the one that is triggering the stack overflow)
2. Go to line 453 add add a breakpoint
3. reload the app, and when it hits the breakpoint just comment it out (setupModuleLoader(window)) and click continue
4. It will still throw an exception, (Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined) but you will be able to run batarang

I know it's not the best solution, but that's the quickest thing I could find without going too deep into the problem

**Update**:

Checking more to what is happening I noticed that the problem happens when we have define multiple modules and we are adding the same dependencies for all of them.

for example:

```
angular.module("app", ["moduleB", "moduleC"]);
angular.module("moduleB", ["moduleC"]);
```

When I define the moduleB without passing the same deps with it's parent module, then there is no stack overflow.

```
angular.module("moduleB", []);
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this, why don't you create a plunker and post this issue on the ngHint github? because it is actually coming from ngHint module and not Batarang itself. Showing how the redundancy is the source of the problem is good

Comment: Good spot!  I've asked the top answer to point to yours as this is both correct and far more useful.

Answer (score 8):

Our team just experienced this error and it was fixed by updating the Batarang Extension in Chrome to the latest.

Comment: This fixes the complete breakage of apps, but it still is throwing some exceptions caused by the extension. You also lose the ability to have a scope inspector, performance tab, dependency graph, options, and the help tab.

Answer (score 0):

Update...
With the new update of Chrome, the problem is back, so if anyone experienced this error, revert back to previous build of Chrome.
All builds available here, don't pick the first one.
http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php
Then it should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with GitHub pages site (with Jekyll).
Searched for hours why does AngularJS app didn't show up (`ng-cloak` was never resolved).
Figured out that was Batarang which causing the issue.

Great thanks for [@kpg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401202/kpg)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394633/4440414).