# angular js tab in developer console in chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

my google chrome is updated recently and there is a angularjs tab in developer console which is causing error to my working application ,causing errors .My app is working perfectly in other browsers and it was working perfectly in chrome also before the update , please help me about this

the tab only occurs when there is app which is made in angularjs is opened

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393367/chrome-extension-hint-js-nghintmodules I think this is your issue, try disabling the AngularJS Batarang chrome extension until they fix the addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Chrome extension Batarang, there was an update made to the extension that breaks angular apps. See https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/163.

Try disabling the extension (if you do have it installed/enabled) and see if it works then. If so, there are steps for installing an older version of the extension here https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/191

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome update from last night breaks our angular application as well, although not entirely.  Our application seems to be executing code before any run blocks are executed, causing fun errors all morning.  I noticed that the console is acting strange as well.  Try evaluating `{ 'a': 'b' }` in the web inspector console. It is unable to do it.

BUT, if you bind it to a variable `var a = { 'a': 'b' }`, it works as expected.

Now, evaluate `{ a: 'b' }` and see that the returned value is `'b'`, which makes no sense to me.  Thanks google!