# AngularJs LoginController not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, batarang

I am getting this strange error :

> Error: The controller function for LoginController could not be found.
>   Is the function registered under that name?

Here is my login controller code :

```
define(
    [
        'app',
    ], function (app) {

        var LoginController = function ($rootScope,$scope,AuthFactory,$location) {

            $scope.login = function(data) {

            }

        };

        LoginController.$inject = ['$rootScope','$scope','AuthFactory', '$location'];
        app.register.controller('LoginController', LoginController);
    });
```

The same code is working fine on Chromium browser, but not on Chrome and firefox.
In the console I see that there is some kind of hint.js being called on top of my application. I am not sure from where is this hint.js file coming from.

Google Chrome Version - Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit), 
Firefox Version - 34.0

Update :

After some googling i found 
[Chrome extension hint.js & ngHintModules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393367/chrome-extension-hint-js-nghintmodules)
which helped me to solve my problem.

My next concern is what if we develop our application and there is AngularJs Batarang enabled on the users system??

Comment: Why don't you use `app.controller('LoginController', function() {})`?

Comment: Well its all the same, I just like it that way! I am using a custom routeResolver.js service to load the controllers based on the route and that's why using app.register.controller(...)

Comment: Does the other way work?